# Action of square root of tridiagonal matrix product on vector

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

Assume nonsymmetric, tridiagonal matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (where $n$ is in the order of 1000) and $A, B, AB$ are diagonalizable and have positive eigenvalues.

How do you efficiently compute the matrix-vector product of 
$$\vec{y}:=\sqrt{A B} \; \vec{x}$$
for a given $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Positive eigenvalues of $A,$ $B$ do not imply positive eigenvalues of $AB$. What is the $\sqrt{AB}$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I edited my question: now A, B, and AB should have positive eigenvalues. Thus, $\sqrt{AB}$ should be uniquely defined.

Comment: How can a matrix always have a square root? Do you also have that the eigenvalues are distinct? Or, is the matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: @vidyarthi Lets assume that the matrix product is diagonalizable.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for you but it's what I'd try:

1. find some way to a priori bound the spectrum of $AB$, and consider a contour $\Gamma$ surrounding the spectrum once counterclockwise and completely contained in the right half-plane
2. Writing $R(z) = (z - AB)^{-1}$ for the resolvent, compute the contour integral of $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_\Gamma \sqrt{z} R(z) x dz$
3. Approximate this integral by quadrature
4. At each quadrature point z_i, you've got to solve (z_i - AB)y = x, which is at least banded.

Comment: I found a Krylov subspace method for symmetric matrices [siam.org](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895479895292400). What about nonsymmetric matrices?

Comment: @pupshaw $\sqrt{z}$ has branched monodromy, how do you compute your contour integral ? (don't you need to do two turns ?) and what is "$x$" in your formula ?

Comment: I thought we were restricting to the positive eigenvalues case, and this is why I restricted to a contour in the right half plane. Can just pick a branch. My x is the same x from the question.

Comment: OK, this might work but what happens if AB is singular ? do you begin with $\sqrt{AB+t}, t>0$ and make $t\to 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

One can use Krylov subspace based methods, i.e. rational Krylov methods work well. There is a paper and matlab code that works out of the box: http://guettel.com/markovfunmv/.

The approach is a *black-box* method that works for arbitrary functions and matrices.
Thus, one might be able to optimize by the given info of positive eigenvalues and square root function.